# Display 3 different views using UIPageControl

Tags: ios, uiview, uipagecontrol

I want to display 3 different views using `UIPageControl`. How can I do it? Please suggest some guidelines or some sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: download sample code from here and see if it helps u
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

You can go through this tutorial http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168